# pass multiple variable from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

error in sending multiple variable from controller to view.
**Error produce in view**

```
Message: Undefined variable: heading
```

Controller Code:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('database');
        $result['a'] = $this->database->factory_view();
        $this->load->view('header');
        $heading['heading']= '<span class="float-left" style="margin-top:10px;"><h3>Machinery and Factory</h3></span>';
        $this->load->view('factory',$result,$heading);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

Comment: put all things in one array and pass in view; it's simple

Answer (score 1):

```
$data['posts'] = $posts;
$data['comments'] = $comments;
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

in view taemplate ...

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
...
}

foreach($comments as $comm) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('database');
    $result['a'] = $this->database->factory_view();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $result['heading']= '<span class="float-left" style="margin-top:10px;"><h3>Machinery and Factory</h3></span>';
    $this->load->view('factory',$result);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like this

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('database');
    $result['a'] = $this->database->factory_view();
    $this->load->view('header');
    $result['heading']= '<span class="float-left" style="margin-top:10px;"> 
  <h3>Machinery and  Factory</h3></span>';
    $result['param_1'] = "xyz";
    $result['param_2'] = "abc";
    $this->load->view('factory',$result);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one out. this will work...

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('database');
        $data['a'] = $this->database->factory_view();
        $this->load->view('header');
        $data['heading']= '<span class="float-left" style="margin-top:10px;"><h3>Machinery and Factory</h3></span>';
        $this->load->view('factory',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

then call the `$a` and `$heading`  inside your **page view**.